Laravel upload multiple images to s3 with spatie/async
I'm using Laravel 10 and I'm trying to upload about 40 images to S3. I keep getting a 500 internal error, and I'm assuming it's because the process is taking too long.
So, I tried to install spatie/async but can't seem to get it to work as I'm still getting a 500 error. Here is my loop:
$pool = Pool::create();

foreach ($matches as $img) {

    $photoURL = $k[$img];
    $filename = Hashids::encode($customerId).'-'.$i.'.jpg';

    $filePath = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower('test/'.str_replace("-", " ", strtolower($k['name'])).'/'.$filename));

    $pool->add(function () use ($photoURL) {
        $contents = Helpers::file_get_contents_curl($photoURL); //uses cURL
        return $contents;
    })->then(function ($contents, $filePath) {
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, $contents, 'public');
    })->catch(function (Throwable $exception) {
        // Handle exception
        dd($exception);
    });
    $newPath = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filePath);
    $arr_images[] = $newPath;

    $i++;
} 
$pool->wait();

dd($arr_images);

What am I doing wrong here? Or is this the best way to upload multiple images at once?
